# Set data on createContext with asynchronous API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a very beginner in React and Next.JS. I'm doing an app and I'm using the useContext hook. So, I have this code

```
import { createContext } from 'react';

let data;
fetch(API_URL)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => {
    data = result.data;
  })
  .catch(error);
  
export const UserContext = createContext(data);
```

The problem is that when the context is created, the value of 'data' is null. Is there a way to do this asynchronously?

Answer (score 0):

1. Something like this should do it:

```
import { useState, useEffect, createContext } from 'react';

const UserContext = ({children}) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const Ctx = createContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(API_URL)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => {
        setData(result.data);
    })
  .catch(error);
  }, []};

  return (
    <Ctx.Provider value = {data} >
      {children}
    </Ctx>
  );
}
```

Didn't test it, but this should give you an idea; You can use it like

```
<UserContext>
  // your code here
</UserContext>
```

2. A better way to do it would be to extract the fetch logic in a custom hook:

```
const data = useUserData(); // fetch logic here
<UserContext value={data}>
  // your code here
</UserContext>
 

 but since you are a beginner in React, I would keep it simple
```